# Overlaying different scenes in the video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image]

I started to divided a video editing project into different scenes, as illustrated in the image below. Here the background, i.e. the clouds, is in scene 1 and the text overlay is in scene 2. While working with scene 2, to position the text, I would like to see scene 1 in the background. Is this possible?

[image: Schematic illustration of the project organization]

Is this the "correct" approach to work with Blender for projects with several text overlays and other visual effects?

A small version of the .blend file without the cloud movie in the background, [can be found here.](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/lztuehtq9a1om/CloudAtlas%5BLIGHT%5D) Note that a still image is located in the stock image folder.

Here are some extra info:

1. The text overlay, i.e. scene 2, is rendered in Blender internal where the shading is set to transparent.
2. In the Video editor the blend type for the strip is set to alpha over.
3. Clouds and text shows up when selecting Scene 1, the background, but the text can not be positioned or adjusted from there.

Comment: Seems good. Just enable transparent background rendering in your Scene 2... But maybe it's enough to just use a simple Text Effect Strip instead?

Comment: "maybe it's enough to just use a simple Text Effect Strip instead?" I condensed down the project to a simple example, the real project contains a large number of  strips, mixed forth and back, that it is getting unmanageable. I added some extra info to the question, I'm not sure where to enable "background rendering"?

Comment: I render out the 1st scene to a single frame .png file and use that as a background pic for the second scene's alignment.  You can alternatively create a temporary video of scene 1 and use that for the background, remove it when you've got the alignment done.  Note that bkd pics have to be viewed through that scene's camera, or when in Orthographic mode.

Comment: To move the text layer in the VSE select that scene strip and add a transform effect to it. For better quality move the text in the source 3D scene.